# Filter App Template - ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, filter, template

I would like to use the [Filter App Template](http://www.arcgis.com/apps/InteractiveFilter/index.html) for an ArcGIS Online Map I'm creating.  I'm working with a water system, and I want the user to be able to use the filters to search for certain junction types (e.g. manholes, fire hydrants, etc.).

While in "Map View" I created filters for each unique value in my "Junction" field.  I selected "Apply Filter and Zoom," but when I go back to the Filter App it says, "Web map does not contain any interactive filters." Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this walkthrough will help you:
http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/01/29/filter-water-utility-assets-by-attributes-in-arcgis-online/

Comment: Well this definitely helped a lot.  I don't get the error message anymore.  I was hoping to get a drop down with every unique value within my Junction field.  I'm still not able to get the drop down.

Comment: Update: I'm now able to search the entire field (which is way better than nothing!).  But I'm still not able to get the drop down.  I may have to give up on that.

Comment: You need to edit the feature class in ArcMap and create a `domain` for the "Junction field". Here is a walkthrough: http://communityhub.esriuk.com/technicalsupport/2013/8/22/how-to-create-drop-down-menus-for-populating-attributes.html